# Analytical Solution of NLS Equation

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations

I am studying about solitons and breathers and right now I am reading this book **"Nonlinear Science Emergence and Dynamics of Coherent Structures by Alwyn Scott"**.

As mentioned in the title I am trying to understand how do we obtain an exact solution of the NLS equation

$\displaystyle \mathrm{i} \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial ^2 u}{\partial x^2} + 2 |u|^2 u = 0$

In the book mentioned above Pg.91 (after doing some calculations) we obtain the system
\begin{cases}
\tilde{\phi}_{xx} - \tilde{\phi}\tilde{\theta}_x^2 + v_c\tilde{\phi}\tilde{\theta}_x + 2\tilde{\phi}^3 = 0 \\[10pt]
\tilde{\phi}\tilde{\theta}_{xx} + 2 \tilde{\phi}_x \tilde{\theta}_x - v_e\tilde{\phi}_x = 0
\end{cases}

Upon multiplying the second equation by $2 \tilde{\phi}$ and then integrating we get $\tilde{\phi}^2(2\tilde{\theta}_x - v_e) =$ constant, which can be solved for $\tilde{\theta}_x$ and substituted in the first equation of the system. After doing some calculations I obtain the following relation

$\displaystyle \iint \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{v_e^2 - 2 v_ev_c}{4} \cdot \tilde{\phi} - 2 \tilde{\phi}^3}} \ d^2 \tilde{\phi} = \pm (x - v_et) $ $\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \bigg($ under the root the fraction is $\displaystyle \frac{v_e^2 - 2 v_ev_c}{4} \bigg)$

Untill now everything is fine. But then it jumps to a single integral given below. What I don't understand is how from the double integral above we go to the single integral

$\displaystyle \int^{\tilde{\phi}} \frac{dy}{\sqrt{P(y)}} = \pm (x - v_et) \ \ $ where $\ \ P(y) = C + \displaystyle \frac{1}{4}(v_e^2 - 2 v_ev_c)y^2 - y^4$

I believe is some transformation and I am trying to figure out which one. Am I missing something here? Thanks for any help.

Comment: What is the double integral over?

Comment: @user619894 At some point I get the relation $d^2 \tilde{\phi} = ...$, so I thought that I should take just the double integral instead of the single indefinite.

Comment: How is $\phi$  related to $u$?

Comment: @user619894 In order to solve NLSE we consider solutions of the form $u(x,t) = \phi (x,t) \cdot e^{i \cdot \theta (x,t)}$. After doing some calculations and equaitng real and imaginary parts we obtain a 2x2 system of $\phi, \theta$. After that we make the transformation $\theta (x,t) = \tilde{\theta}(x-v_ct)$ and $\phi (x,t) = \tilde{\phi}(x- v_et)$ and we obtain the system above.

Comment: How does this explain the double integral? I think something is missing

Comment: @user619894 I used double integral because of the $d^2 \tilde{\phi}$. I thought of it like integrating over $d  \tilde{\phi}$ and then again over $d  \tilde{\phi}$. But after that, in the book I am studying he just goes to single integral.

Comment: we are going around in circles. why is their a $d^2\phi$ at all?

Comment: @user619894 Because after we make a substitution on the first equation and we try to integrate it we have this term $\tilde{\phi}_{xx} = \frac{d^2 \tilde{\phi}}{dx^2}$.

Comment: the integration is over $dx$, isn`t it?

Comment: @user619894 I think he did something like separation of virables. I try to understand it myself so if I say something wrong Im sorry.